# Problem with has_many :through Association in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, associations, has-many

I've got a problem with a has_many :through association, i cant call the `u1.UsersProfileAttributes.find_by_ProfileAttribute_name("icq")` method, rails means that this method doesn't exist. The method `u1.UsersProfileAttributes.find_by_ProfileAttribute_id(3)` works correctly. u1 is a user object. I don't know whats the problem, because my associations seems to be okay. Have a look:

```
class ProfileAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :UsersProfileAttributes
  has_many :users, :through => :UsersProfileAttributes
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :UsersProfileAttributes
  has_many :ProfileAttributes, :through => :UsersProfileAttributes
end
class UsersProfileAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ProfileAttribute
end
```

My Migration file:

```
    class CreateProfileAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :profile_attributes do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.integer :profile_group_id
          t.timestamps
        end
    create_table :users_profile_attributes do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :ProfileAttribute_id  
      t.string :value
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :profile_attributes
    drop_table :users_profile_attributes
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query ProfileAttributes, not UsersProfileAttributes.  This should work for you: `u1.ProfileAttributes.find_by_name('icq')`

`u1.UsersProfileAttributes.find_by_ProfileAttribute_id(3)` works because `ProfileAttribute_id` is an attribute of `UsersProfileAttribute` ... so ActiveRecord builds you a dynamic finder.

`u1.UsersProfileAttributes.find_by_ProfileAttribute_name("icq")` does not work because `ProfileAttribute_name` is not an attribute of `UsersProfileAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks, thats right. 
Another Questioen: Is there a simple methode to create or alter the releationship. Id do it like that now: upa = UsersProfileAttribute?.new(:user => u, :ProfileAttribute? => pa, :value => "Profil Wert") 
u is a user object and pa is a ProfileAttribute object. A 1 line methode would be nice, e.g. that the ProfileAttribute is generated automaticaly or something like that?

Comment: Another Question: how can i alter the value of a known ProfileAttribute for a specific user?